# How to use $\binom$ command in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: math-mode

I was trying to insert $\binom {s}{t-1}$ in Texnic Center but the output in PDF was just st-1. Is there a way to install this command or something like that? Can someone please help?
Thank You.

Comment: this is unrelated to texniccenter which is just the editor you are using to write the file. `\binom` is defined in `amsmath` package so add `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Answer (score 3):

This is unrelated to texniccenter which is just the editor you are using to write the file. `\binom` is defined in `amsmath` package so add `\usepackage{amsmath}`.